# Format output of csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with non-ascii text (Chinese characters) that is something like this:

```
id,name1,category,name2,name3  
cn,北京,capital,北京,北京  
cn,南京,city,南京,南京  
jp,東京,capital,東京,江戸
```

I'm trying to write this file into a particular format, where the names are group by the category like this:

```
"A list of capitals are:  
北京(cn)  
北京(cn)  
北京(cn)  
東京(jp)  
東京(jp)  
江戸(jp) 

A list of cities are:  
南京(cn)  
南京(cn)  
南京(cn)"
```

In other words, the output would be like:

```
A list of $category values are
$name1 $id
$name2 $id
$name3 $id
```

I got up to creating a dictionary with the category as key and the names are values but when I try to write this dictionary, the text is not displayed properly.

This is my code:

```
import csv  
cases = {}  
with open('filename.csv', mode='rU') as f:  
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')  
for n, row in enumerate(reader):  
if not n:  
    #Skip header row (n = 0).  
    continue  
id,name1,category,name2,name3 = row  
if category not in cases:  
    cases[category] = list()  
cases[category].append((name2,name3))  
print(cases)
```

Comment: Should be moved to stackoverflow, because it's about Python.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

To sort by column 3:

```
tail -n +2 test | sort -k2 | awk -F, '{print $2" "$1}'
```

---

Python is really cool but IMHO there are some things concerning encodings (binary/utf-8/etc) like in `os.walk` which are not so cool.

Since we're in the `unix world` here is a solution using `awk` which might just do the job in a oneliner out of the box.

Assuming your csv file is called `test` and the first line in it is the table header:

```
cat test | awk -F "," '{if (NR>1){print $2" "$1}}'
```

input test:

```
id,name1,category,name2,name3  
cn,北京,capital,北京,北京  
cn,南京,city,南京,南京  
jp,東京,capital,東京,江戸
```

output:

```
北京 cn
南京 cn
東京 jp
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response!! My issue is that I also want to group the names by category (column #3) and then create a formatted file..

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, ***Python*** solution:

```
import collections, csv

with open('yourfile.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)  # dictionary-like object
    for row in reader:
        for i in range(1,4):    # iterating through `name` fields
            d[row['category']].append("%s(%s)" % (row['name' + str(i)], row['id']))

print(dict(d))
```

The output:

```
{'capital': ['北京(cn)', '北京(cn)', '北京(cn)', '東京(jp)', '東京(jp)', '江戸(jp)'], 'city': ['南京(cn)', '南京(cn)', '南京(cn)']}
```

---

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html?highlight=csvreader#csv.DictReader
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Thanks so much. I got encoding is not a valid argument using your code... I'm updating the question with my current code which prints out the dictionary but does not display the characters properly.

Comment: @user221873, it works fine with your input example. Tested on Python 3.5

Comment: Thanks!! I'm using python 2.7, perhaps that's why we see a difference??